# How to convert an audio output signal to input signal?

Tags: audio

I have a music calculator, which has an audio output port. So I can plug in headphones or speaker on it.

But now i want to connect it to a computer as input signal like microphone.

Is there any convertor or circuit can solve the problem?
Or any good idea or recommend? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a male-to-male 3.5mm audio cable like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0793KTNJY) to connect the music calculator to the PC's microphone or 'AUX' jack. It will work just like a microphone.